# Hacer un foreach de una data SOAP

Tags: flutter, soap

Estoy intentando traer los datos de una bd a traves de SOAP. Tengo el código y consigo verlo en la consola pero después no puedo hacer un foreach por cada uno.

Con el siguiente código:

```
final resp = await http.post(
  _baseUrl,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    "SOAPAction": "http://xxxxxx.org/Cliente_Lista"
  },
  body: _body,
);

Xml2Json xml2json = Xml2Json();
xml2json.parse(resp.body);
final jsondata = xml2json.toParker();
final data = json.decode(jsondata);

print(data);
```

me imprime esto:

> "flutter: {soap:Envelope: {soap:Body: {Cliente_ListaResponse: {Cliente_ListaResult: {Clientes: [{Codigo: 5564, CodigoAnterior: null, Don: DOÑA, Nombre: ROSA MARIA"

Sin embargo cuanto más abajo pongo el siguiente código:

```
  data.forEach((key, value) {
  final tempClient = Clientes.fromMap(value);
  tempClient.codigo = key;
  this.clients.add(tempClient);

  print(tempClient.nombre);
});
```

Me devuelve `flutter:null`

Para conseguir que me devuelva el nombre o cualquier otra cosa tengo que poner:

```
data['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body']['Cliente_ListaResponse']
    ['Cliente_ListaResult']['Clientes'][0]['Nombre']
```

Y así el forEach da el siguiente error:

> "_TypeError (type '(dynamic, dynamic) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => dynamic' of 'f')"

Comment: El JSON que pusiste, está incompleto pero bueh, se entiende maomenos de qué va. Tienes que iterar sobre `Clientes` como ya viste, porque el XML en la respuesta efectivamente tiene todos esos niveles: El envelope, el cuerpo, el Response, el elemento Result que contiene lo que se supone que te entrega y ya ahí dentro, los conjuntos de datos prometidos, N elementos dentro de Clientes. Te falta decirnos cómo intentaste el forEach. Por favor, [edit] la pregunta y añádelo

Comment: Gracias @Alfabravo, por tu respuesta he editado la pregunta no se si con lo que querias saber, la verdad que soy muy nuevo. Si me puedes poner un ejemplo que lo vea mas claro como iterar con Clientes porque creo que así lo hacia.